# How to: Select from MYSQL text field type only the numbers that divided by | using REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, regex

I got the table, that containing the field filled digits (1-2 symbol each) like this (1|5|18|44|98|22), also field can contain only one digit (without divider **|**)
How can I search in this field certain digits?
For example - i need to select the rows, contains only 5. Or only 18 and 44?

Comment: First you start by redesigning your tables and split that data into a seperate child table. Then the rest of your question becomes academic.

Comment: Read this [blog](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add pipes to the start and end of the field like this while querying.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR TABLE
WHERE INSTR( CONCAT('|', field, '|'), '|1|' ) >0
```

will return your row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR TABLE
WHERE INSTR( CONCAT('|', field, '|'), '|31|' ) >0
```

will not find and no rows will return.

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR TABLE
WHERE (INSTR(concat('|',field,'|'), '|18|') >0 and INSTR(concat('|',field,'|'), '|44|') >0)
```

will return if 18 and 44 both in your field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '(^|\|)digit_you_want_add_here($|\|)'`